# How to use different routes for sections of the same page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing in Rails 3 and have a html document with the following structure:

```
<div id="one">

</div>

<div id="two">

</div>

<div id="three">

</div>
```

I can link to sections by going to the address: /index#one, /index#two and /index#three. Is it possible to give these a specific named route in rails? Something like:

```
match '/one',   :to => 'pages#index#one'
match '/two',   :to => 'pages#index#two'
match '/three', :to => 'pages#index#three'
```

I'd rather actually name the route, than put the hash into the address bar, if that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the user agent, not the server, that determines to jump to an anchor. having the anchor in the URL is the best way to do this, though if you really don't like it, you could probably work out a way to emulate it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the views, you can use the `:anchor` parameter to modify the named routes, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'One', pages_path(:anchor => 'one') %>
```

That's how I would do it.

**Edit:** I think I misunderstood your problem. You want completely distinct URLs which redirect to different anchors on an identical page, right?

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea, since if you have links to the different sections in the document, they will produce a page reload which is normally not necessary for anchors. You'd also need some JavaScript workaround for behavior which is automatically handled by the browser if done the usual way.